# Orbot doesn't start after the first time i used it

Tags: orbot

I used Orbot for about 2 weeks. Then I uninstalled the app. 2 Days ago I reinstalled it and when I pressed the button nothing happened while in the log on the left the only thing that shows is:

> found polipo PID:6820 - killing now....

It writes this thing 5 or 6 times, then the app shuts down saying that it has stopped working. I tried to change the proxy and port on my wireless connection but nothing changed.